# Drawings, clocks and other designs not showing up on conky, only text is being shown

Tags: desktop, conky

Here's how they are supposed to look.

[image: one]

[image: two]

Here's how they look

[image: my desktop]

The middle one's supposed to be the breaking bad widget but the lines don't show and the right one's supposed to look like the first picture but again the designs don't show up. What could be the issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem like it has anything to do with elementary OS. You should seek help from a Conky community